# What is the biblical basis for a one world religion in the end times?

Tags: biblical-basis, eschatology, revelation, signs-of-the-times

I was just reading about eschatology and somebody was stating that this verse suggests that there will be a one world religion, a false religion:

> [Revelation 17:1–18 (ESV)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation+17:1-18&version=ESV)
>
> 1 Then one of the seven angels who had the seven bowls came and said
>   to me, “Come, I will show you the judgment of the great prostitute who
>   is seated on many waters, 2 with whom the kings of the earth have
>   committed sexual immorality ...

Where is support for this concept found in other scriptures?

Comment: I don't see what that verse has to do with religion, unless the "one world religion" was a fertility cult with sacred prostitutes.

Comment: I sense your sarcasm (so I assume you're joking)... Some people think that the RC church is the "great prostitute" (not trying to offend any RC's-- I was one for many years!). in Ezekiel 23, Israel and Samaria are also compared to prostitutes; if this verse does refer to a one-world religion, it wouldn't be the first time that prostitution was used as an allegory for idolatry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a lot of discussion and debate about this especially due to the nature of the end-time prophecies, but one verse that does back a one world religion at least implicitly.

> ### [Rev 13:8](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=rev%2013:8&version=NLT)
>
> And all the people who belong to this world worshiped the beast. They
>   are the ones whose names were not written in the Book of Life before
>   the world was made—the Book that belongs to the Lamb who was
>   slaughtered

If everyone is worshiping the "beast" then in essence the religion is the same, whether it is actually one religion or not.

Comment: You have to remember that Revelation is deeply symbolic. It may or may not be an actual religion, any more than "serving Mammon" needs to be an actual religion.

Comment: True, but it appears to be the best direct evidence supporting the position of a one world religion. But I've edited my answer a bit to respect the symbolic nature of revelations.

Comment: Agreed. Revelation is certainly the best evidence.

Comment: I believe the "beast" refers to the devil.  KJV of this verse: "And all that dwell upon the earth shall worship him, whose names are not written in the book of life of the Lamb slain from the foundation of the world."

Comment: I think it's entirely possible that the "one world religion" may be Atheism.

Answer (score 1):

**Oneness?** It is a common modern fad these days for prophecy teachers to dwell on Oneness: One world government, One world religion, etc. And they find a bunch of verses cherry-picked from the Old and New Testaments, that they shuffle together like a deck of cards, and then lay them out as a prophetic timeline for the "End-times" or "Last Days."

In all these cases, when exposition verse-by-verse is done exegetically, these modern interpretations fail.  Instead of picking out verses hither and yon, when context is considered---and verses are kept in their context---there are no end-time conspiracies seen.

What is overlooked in the verse referred to in this posting, is that it appears in an Apocalypse **not** in a prophetic book. The type of **genre** is overlooked, and therefore the verses are wrongfully interpreted.  The symbolism is minimized, and literalism is exaggerated.

No one should delve into Revelation without first mastering the message of Matthew-to-Jude scriptures! When one does so, two things become apparent:

**1.** The **last days** began in the first century, and continue until the Second Coming. Therefore, there are no "last days" as an End-time scenario. The Church Age (Kingdom of Heaven instituted by Jesus) lasts consistently until the Return of Christ (Hebrews 9:28, Matthew 13 See the Parables of the Kingdom).

**2,** There are no **signs of the times** to signal the End, or end-times. Jesus repeated this for emphasis!

> [The people of Noah's day] **knew not** until the flood came, and took them all away; so shall also the coming of the Son of Man be. (Matthew 24:39)

> Watch therefore, for you know not what hour your Lord shall come (24:42)

> Therefore be ye also ready, for in such an hour as ye think not the Son of Man cometh. (24:44)

> Watch therefore, for ye know neither the day nor the hour wherein the Son of Man cometh. (25:13)

Now if there were horrendous events or diabolical institutions (such as One World anything) preceeding the immediate Second Coming, then Jesus's warning would be feckless. People "would know" the end was near.

But Jesus declared no one will know when the end is near. Jesus repeated this dilemma just before He ascended:

> It is not for you to know the times or the seasons which the Father has put in His own power. (Acts 1:7)

Any scriptural interpretation in the most symbolic Apocalyptic book cannot contradict the teachings of Jesus in the plain, clear scriptures in Matthew-to-Jude. That is just good hermeneutics.

And the teachings of Jesus cannot be supraceeded by Darbyism or any man-made schema that teaches differently. Eisegesis has no place in hermeneutics. *There is no support in other scriptures outside Revelation for any One World Religion*.

{As an aside, a survey of world history, and a recall of the purpose of God's division at Babel, demonstrate vividly that any **one-world-ness** is an utter impossibility in human events! The diversity of philosophies, differences of cultures, variety of world religions, all militate against there ever being a one world religion! The struggles for dominance, the wars for conquest, the selfish greed of humanity...all block the institution of a one world anything.}

Answer (score 0):

This chapter was actually the focus of our message this past weekend.  What I recall from the message was that the woman represents Babylon.

> **[Revelation 17:5 NIV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=rev%2017:5&version=NIV)**
>   5 The name written on her forehead was a mystery:
>
> BABYLON THE GREAT
>
> THE MOTHER OF PROSTITUTES
>
> AND OF THE ABOMINATIONS OF THE EARTH.

I believe in this context, Babylon referred to large, conquering empires in the past, present (Rome), and future.

> **[Revelation 17:15-16 NIV](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Revelation%2017:15-16&version=NIV)**
>   15 Then the angel said to me, “The waters you saw, where the
>   prostitute sits, are peoples, multitudes, nations and languages.  16 The beast and the ten horns you saw will hate the prostitute. They will bring her to ruin and leave her naked; they will eat her flesh and burn her with fire.

Verse 16 says these empires will be brought down.

<sub>(If you're interested in the message, it's 08.28.11 in the [archive](http://onlinecfc.com/weekend-service/message-archive-recent-messages-notes/))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

To some Christians, Hanukkah foreshadows the Antichrist cf. YouTube videos [1](https://youtu.be/deK4TOJ2cNE) & [2](https://youtu.be/JRJUP4YOpg0) posted *by Connie Oelbaum*.

The groups make the connection from Christ's words when he foretells of [the desolating sacrilege](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2024%3A15-28&version=RSVCE) as one of the signs preceeding the End of the Age. [Cf. [Mt. 24](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Matthew%2024&version=RSVCE)].

The type of what is to come is **The Books of Maccabees**: the background of both books is the resistance movement against the hellenisation of the Jewish nation by the Seleucid kings. From the books we find:

1) [1 Macc (RSVCE)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Maccabees%201&version=RSVCE) especially [vv. 41-64](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Maccabees%201%3A41-64&version=RSVCE) (Installation of Gentile Cults), where *the king wrote to his whole kingdom that all should be one people, and that each should give up his customs [...] and **[adopt] his religion**.*

2) Jason, who usurped the high-priesthood by underhand methods, introducing hellenism and Greek customs. [Cf. [2 Macc 4:7-29 (RSVCE)](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=2%20Maccabees%204%3A7-29&version=RSVCE)].

---

---

This is my thinking as well. Cf. [This post](https://shyanguya.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/why-the-catholic-church-is-true-the-books-of-maccabees/) and [this](https://shyanguya.wordpress.com/2014/07/03/the-pious-high-priest-and-the-godless-and-not-true-high-priest/) on my blog.

Answer (score 0):

It may well be an installation of a cult. Currently, many nation's leaders worship Baphomet, a beast made from Deuteronomy 4, a winged creature with horns, hooved feet, and both male and female. This Baphomet cult worships Satan and Fallen angels. They follow Satanic sacrifices of humans and animals, practice color and clothing Magick, and use a Satanic kabbalah for manifestations of their evil intent.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center's](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Karinah, and for your interesting comments. However, answers on this site require evidence in support of claims made, and in this case the Bible's evidence is sought regarding a modern situation.  If you could add more along those lines, that would be good.

Answer (score 0):

**Introduction:** A great deal has changed over the last 12 years since this question was asked. Just as the United Nations, the International Monetary Fund and other institutions have made it clear that their objective is to establish a One World Government and a One World Bank, so too have various mainstream religions expressed not just tolerance towards other faiths but a willingness to embrace people of all faiths, as well as people of no faith. You must not criticise any other religion, regardless of their actions against, for example, Christians who are being persecuted. Governments and media are bending over backwards to accommodate every whim, every demand, every supposed right of minority groups, whilst silencing any person who dares to challenge or question what they are up to. Freedom of speech has been seriously curtailed, and freedom of Christian worship is being stifled.

**What does any of this have to do with Revelation?**  A great deal, but it is not ‘Babylon the Great’ the harlot riding the scarlet beast, who will be torn down from her lofty position and destroyed that should be the focus of our attention. No, we have to find out what the Entity is behind the political and religious elements, the Entity that is manipulating and controlling world events. The Entity is not physical – it is not some man or some organisation. The Entity is satanic and is (literally) hell-bent on destroying humanity before the return of Christ Jesus.

**Revelation is a graphic, symbolic vision,** given to the apostle John, pointing forward in time to the great tribulation and the coming of the Antichrist, who is still to be revealed. Numbers convey ideas, not arithmetic. Forms display concepts, not shapes. Words are clothed in mystery, not logic. The "beasts" are not literal, but are symbolic.

**Revelation chapter 13 describes two beasts**, one that comes out of the sea and one that comes out of the earth. Verses 1 to 9 describe a one world government that opposes all who belong to Christ.

> The dragon gave the beast [out of the sea] his power and his throne and great authority.  One of the heads of the beast seemed to have had a fatal wound, but the fatal wound had been healed. The whole world was astonished and followed the beast.  Men worshipped the dragon because he had given authority to the beast, and they also worshipped the beast, and asked, ‘Who is like the beast?  Who can make war against him?’

> He opened his mouth to blaspheme God, and to slander his name and his dwelling place and those who live in heaven. He was given power to make war against the saints and to conquer them. And he was given authority over every tribe, people, language and nations. All inhabitants of the earth will worship the beast – all whose names have not been written in the book of life belonging to the Lamb that was slain from the creation of the world.

**The beast that comes out of the earth** exercises all the authority of the first beast on his behalf, and makes the inhabitants worship the first beast, whose fatal wound had been healed. Revelation 13:11-17 describes how this second beast deceives the inhabitants of the earth:

> He ordered them to set up an image in honour of the beast who was wounded by the sword and yet lived.  He was given power to give breath to the image of the first beast, so that it could speak and cause all who refused to worship the image to be killed.

**Summary:** The first beast is a ten-horned, seven-headed monstrosity empowered and given authority by a dragon (Revelation 13:1–2). One of the heads is mortally wounded but is healed (verse 3). The beast is blasphemous against God and actively persecutes God’s people on earth (verses 5–7). It not only rules the world but receives the worship of the world’s inhabitants (verses 4, 7–8). The first beast is a symbolic picture of the Antichrist, and the dragon is Satan (cf. Revelation 12:9).

The second beast is a two-horned, deceptively benign creature that shares authority with the first beast (Revelation 13:11–12). The task of the second beast is to cause everyone to worship the first beast.  As the second beast deceives the world with miracles, it orders that everyone “set up an image in honour of the beast who was wounded by the sword and yet lived” (verse 14).  It also requires that everyone receive the mark of the beast in their forehead or right hand (verses 16–17). The second beast is a symbolic picture of the false prophet.

The Bible does not provide many details concerning the image of the beast. What we are told is that the false prophet will have “power to give breath to the image of the first beast so that the image could speak” (Revelation 13:15). This breathing, speaking image of the beast will then demand worship. Anyone who refuses to worship the image of the beast will be killed. Revelation 20:4 says that the mode of execution for those who do not worship the image of the beast is beheading.

**Answer:** These verses in the book of Revelation describe how the Entity behind the dragon and the beasts will influence world governments to come together and force humanity to worship the image of the beast. If they do not worship this image, they will be killed. That is the “one world religion” that is depicted. It is not a church. It is not Christianity or Islam or Buddhism, or Hinduism or any other established religion. It is anti-God and anti-Christ. That is the purpose of the Antichrist – to stop people from giving worship to the Creator. Instead, people will turn to science, to politics, to money – indeed to anything except God. They will be worshiping Satan, the Entity behind it all.